# iOS: Text is not displayed inside of a rotated UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, landscape

I have created a UITextField with Interface Builder.  In `viewDidLoad`, I rotate the text field to match the landscape view we need:

```
name.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-(M_PI/2));
```

Unfortunately, this does not bring the text with it.  The text sits outside of the textfield, behind the background, as seen below.

[image: Note the where the suggestion box is.]

Based on other questions here at StackOverflow, I have tried:

```
name.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
name.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

and this additional function:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    name.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    name.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
}
```

Neither solution works.

**-----UPDATE-----**

I was able to just orient the nib for landscape rather than portrait, and that solved the problem.  However, this seems like a bug.  I'd assume a rotated UITextField should bring the text with it.

Comment: Why are you doing these instructions? It's a default behaviour, just provide new frame for new orientation in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method.

Comment: @beryllium I'm not sure what you mean by "frame".  Besides that, I'm just trying everything I can to get the text back in the box, and those "solutions" were the closest thing I could find through Google/StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you rotating the text field manually? Just let your UIViewController do its normal rotation behaviour (which transforms the view controller's main view) and all the subviews will be usable in landscape.

Comment: This is really the correct *question*.  Initially, when we started building the view with IB, orienting the nib for "Landscape" left us with a view that was Landscape **within** a portrait mode view, so half of the view would be hanging off the screen.  We worked around it by orienting it for portrait and just rotating all objects.  We should've investigated further, because 5 minutes of Googling after seeing your answer brought me to setting the proper value in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Honestly, I have no idea why setting that transform would cause the text field to break, but I bet you'd see a lot of built-in subclasses would break if you transformed them. (Since their frame is no longer meaningful.)